# Created QUERY, need data to display inside drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to modify a webpage right now that uses PHP and HTML.

Basically I have a list of items that are generated. The values could be 1, or 10 depending on the row length.

Beside each list item I have a "delete" button, right now I have it working to delete but I need to create a confirmation dialog pop up.

Everything works, but for some reason only the FIRST button in the list with the id that goes to my JavaScript launches.

In essence, after my PHP loop runs, I will have this line of code on an HTML page about 5 times.

```
<input type="button" id="btnShowSimple" value="Simple Dialog" />
```

My javascript looks for when "btnShowSimple" is clicked, but for some reason only the first one has the function assigned to it, when they all have the same ID?

Comment: You're not duplicating IDs are you?

Comment: @j08691 hmm `to basically have an html page with two buttons, both same ID,`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ - It was kind of a rhetorical question.

Comment: i know :P  was a rhetorical response lol

Answer (score 1):

`id`s are unique on a web page. If you use classes instead, you can get all of the elements with that class name. Here is an example with classes:

```
<input type="button" class="btnShowSimple" value="Simple Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 1):

generate unique id's say

```
$i=1;
foreach($result as $row) {
echo '<input type="button" class="btnShowSimple" id="dialog['.$i.']" value="Simple Dialog" />';
$i++;
}
```

now use javascript to see if class btnShowSimple is clicked then get this elements id and now you can do whatever you intend to do.

Comment: i mean now you can display the dialog box which is related to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Also, it would be easier to just add an onclick attribute to your buttons, like this...

```
<input type="button" class="btnShowSimple" id="{$UniqueID}" onclick="delete_function(this);" value="Simple Dialog" />
```

Then for your JavaScript...

```
function delete_function(btn) {
    //handle delete stuff here
    var id = btn.id; //this is the unique id from the button

    //for a confirm box
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ID: " + id + "?")) {
        //yep
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are duplicating the id's of the elements. HTML id's should be unique. I'd recommend using your code to get the number of elements you'll be adding, and then making the id's "btnShowSimple-n" where n is the number of the element.

Comment: ok, what about the javascript code, how can i make it recognize the class instead of ID? ...  $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) is what I am using

Comment: Add a class to the buttons, and then change `$("#btnShowSimple")` to `$(".yourClassName")`